# Android parsing inner xml tags and TextView

Tags: android, xml, dom

I'm working on somekind of subtitle engine.
This is the line of text that I get:

```
<p begin="00:01:14.574" end="00:01:16.410">TEXT1 <span tts:fontStyle="italic">TEXT2</span></p>
```

Now I need to set both texts to TextView but second part of text needs to be italic in this case.
Span tag also can contain fontColor, fontFamilty, fontStroke, etc.

When I'm parsing DOM document I find paragraph element by:
    NodeList paragraphNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("p");

And now I have problem derivating which part of string is wrapped by span tag.

If I use paragraphElement.getTextContent()
I get TEXT1+TEXT2.

But I need somehow to decide which part of text if wrapped, and in case of italic, my final string needs to look:

TEXT1 + < i > + TEXT2 + < /i>

so textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(finalString)) would give me wanted result.

I hope that you can understand my problem here.

Comment: use a SpannableString and style them

Comment: Ok I intended to do so, after I parse those data. I can't find out which part of text is wrapped with span tag.

Comment: i don't understand can you post your code

Comment: how would you differentaite beween text1 and text2 aree the separated by space or it is single world?

Comment: between those two lines i can have span tag that has dynamic number of attributes.

Comment: Anybody? I have edited my question again, for some reason xml code wasn't shown. There now you can see example line that I'm trying to parse and to handle.